# cannot resolve method getMap() : AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity class goes like this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AddPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Lint shows an error like this in my code : "**cannot resolve method getMap();"**

The code snippet is: `

```
    MapFragment fm = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager() 
    .findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
    map = fm.getMap();

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

    mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true); 
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);`
```

I have tried to replace `getMap();` with `getMapAsync();` :

```
        public class AddPostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post);

            MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
            fm.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();
                mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
                mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }


    }
```

**But appears public (of the second class) in red line**

How can I add the code of the `OnMapReadyCallback` in my first public class, so that it appears as a duplicate public class, not giving errors?

**XML**

```
  <fragment android:id="@+id/maps_fragment" 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Have you added a map in your xml file?

Comment: post your activity xml file

Comment: You should use SupportMapFragment I guess

Comment: did you install the Google Apis ?

Comment: @mastec2 share your xml layout please ?

Comment: <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/maps_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: You are saying you have an error at statement "public" class AddPostActivity?

Comment: public class AddPostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback    : PUBLIC APPEARS ON RED LINE HERE

Comment: What is that error can u tell us?

Comment: i have open 2 public class in one activity ? Can i do this ? the second public class appears on red line

Comment: No you can't.. Which is the first class then?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, Click on Red Bulb which appears on the left side of the error line and just implement the methods needed by that interface and also don't forget to add dependency for google-play-services

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AddPostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: So u have created 2 classes with same name in the same file.? Please comment the first class and keep the second one only.

Comment: Don't post your code in comments, Instead update your question with your new code snippet

Comment: here i have all the code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypmymzs9id45xe9/activity.txt?dl=0

Comment: I didn't see the second class in that code??

Comment: If i delete or comment the first class and use only the second class that implement the OnMapReadycallback is ok ?

Comment: code updated : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f8oyet57j0ti7n/sddd.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to find where the problem could. Let you try these lines.

**If you implement the OnMapReadyCallback you need to override the onMapReady function.**

```
public class GetLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
...
.
gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
R.id.gmap)).getMap();
..
..

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
 // your logic here
}

}
```

**EDITED:**

Remove these lines from your code. [ remove completely your second class]

Then make you first class to implement the onMapReadyCallback.

Then copy the necessary variables and logic to your first class itself.

// Remove below lines from your code.

```
public class AddPostActivity extends AddPostActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private UiSettings mUiSettings;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_post_activity);

        MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
        fm.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

        mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    }
    }
```

Instead implement the same logic in your first class itself. Let me know for queries

Comment: i not have a getlocationactivity, i can add this ?

Comment: error appears on the secon public class, wich appears in red line